# Ubuntu only starts at boot. No option to boot windows

Tags: dual-boot

I just completed my dual boot with ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8.1.

There was no option to install ubuntu along side with windows so I used the something else option.

I had shrunk my C drive and got 215 gb of free space and used all that space for ubuntu. I could not get option to allocate swap so i didnt use swap.

After the completion of installation my computer boots only to Ubuntu. There is no option to choose windows.

Can any one help me to solve the problem.

I had my UEFI boot option off.

Comment: Boot into ubuntu open terminal Ctl+Alt+T and type "sudo update-grub" and reboot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual boot Win 8 / Ubuntu loads only Win](http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win)

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu starts without Windows option? "Ubuntu only starts in Dual boot" does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your grub boot options. Open your shell from either the menu, or by pressing the global keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T, and enter the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Upon reboot you should have a timer, and the full list of installed operating systems on your computer.

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but it just repeats the comment by DnrDevil, without giving credit.

Comment: Updating the grub solved my problem. Thanks a lot man. Can you please tell me why we need to update the grub. Why it didnt detect the windows.

Comment: on the newer versions I have noticed that the installer does not, for some reason, scan the installed OSes. So running this does the scan post install.

Comment: @Bikram If this helped you solve your problem, consider accepting this answer (clicking the check on the left) to let others with the same problem know which answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem back in 12.04, I solved it by installing the rEFInd Boot Manager. If you have a UEFI system (it most likely is if it came with Windows) this might work.

To install rEFInd:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install refind
```

It will ask you if you want to install rEFInd to your ESP, say yes.

Reboot to save changes.

More info can be found [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html)

Comment: This looks good, and could work as a last resort but you should mention that `rEFInd` is a boot loader and will replace `grub` on the system, probably not a good option for beginners.